# hiding a navbar element on certain pages in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a navbar and a search field on that. I dont want to show the search field on my home page and search page. I tried like below code but its not working... But If i try only one like `<% if params[:action] != 'home' %>` in below code then it work.  Is the or symbol allowed in views??Could someone tell me what i am doing wrong here?

```
<% if params[:action] != 'search' || 'home' %>
  <%= form_tag search_path, class: "navbar-form navbar-left", method: :get do %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search your product?", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: or symbol allowed but the syntax here is wrong. try `unless ["search", "home"].include?(params[:action])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<% if params[:action] != 'search' || 'home' %>`

This will always compare params[:action] with `search`.

As `'search' || 'home'` will always return `search`.

`'search' || 'home'` this expression says if first argument is **false** then return 2 argument.

`false || 'home'` this expression will return `home` as first argument is **false**.

Try this:
In future you can add more actions in array:

```
<% unless ["search", "home"].include?(params[:action]) %>
  <%= form_tag search_path, class: "navbar-form navbar-left", method: :get do %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search your product?", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<% if (params[:action] != 'search') && (params[:action] != 'home') %>
  <%= form_tag search_path, class: "navbar-form navbar-left", method: :get do %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search your product?", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This should work. In your code 'home' always evaluates to true.

Answer (score 1):

you are comparing action only against search change your code to

```
<% if params[:action] != 'search' || params[:action] != 'home' %>
  <%= form_tag search_path, class: "navbar-form navbar-left", method: :get do %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search your product?", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```